# < is red underlined in activity_main

Tags: android

The `<` in my `activity_main.xml` is red-underlined. Why is that?

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
android:id="@+id/fab"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

The `<` in the `android.support.v7.widget-Toolbar` and in `android.support-design.widget.FloatActionButton` lines is underlined, indicating a syntactical error. What is wrong?

Comment: Can you post the entire file?

Answer (score 0):

It may be that you didn't include the XML header.  All layout XML files should begin with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

I assume you have some sort of Layout around your widgets also. Here is a simple, working example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.sample.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
    android:src="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email" />
```

Comment: yeah but i have to put something into a <Layout [..] </layout>  ... should this code be in the layout? because in the book he hasnt these whole code ( like you )

Comment: In the example above a <CoordinatorLayout/> is used.  You can use any of the layouts:  http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html